# Simple use of variable with select * in Oracle

Tags: oracle, variables, oracle-sqldeveloper

I know MSSQL very well. But when trying some basic things of SQL in Oracle I am getting in trouble. Tried to search on other sites but didn't found proper + simple example. 
Suppose I have SQL statements as follows

```
Declare @mID int = 45
Select * from MyTable where id= @mID
```

I tried to write same code in Oracle (SQL Developer). But it didn't worked.

```
Declare 
mID number := 45
Begin
Select * from MyTable where id= mID
End;
```

Actually, I tried some more statements but didn't executed. All I got was ERRORS.
Can anyone come  up with simple & correct solution?

Comment: In what sense did it not work? Does it not give the expected output or is there an error message?

Comment: I want help in creating statements for oracle

Comment: I got errors. I don't know proper syntax.

Comment: You can't execute simple `SELECT` in PL/SQL. You need to put it in some record- or table-type variable.

Comment: You are missing a `;` after the `end` statement. - If that still won't work, try to add a `:` before the second occurrence of variable `mID` to expand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not have variables in SQL, only in PL/SQL. And unlike SQL Server where everything is "T-SQL", Oracle makes a clear distinction between SQL and (procedural) PL/SQL.

Variables in *SQL* statements must be done (supported) by the **SQL Client**, not the server.

SQL Developer supports (client side) variables the same way as SQL*Plus does it.

```
define mid = 45
Select * 
from MyTable 
where id= &mid;
```

The `DEFINE` command is documented here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve017.htm#i2697507

(I don't usually use SQL Developer so I don't know if this is also documented in the manual there)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for in the comment to the previous answer. I am interested to read more on this. Can you point me to some good references please?

Comment: Check the link to the SQL*Plus manual. SQL Developer supports most of it and check the SQL Developer manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/doc.112/e12152/intro.htm#CHDDHAAI

Comment: Thanks. But I am actually interested to learn in depth on what your answer just said. `Variables in SQL statements must be done (supported) by the SQL Client, not the server.

SQL Developer supports (client side) variables the same way as SQL*Plus does it.`

Comment: Variables in SQL\*Plus *are* explained in the SQL\*Plus manual.

Answer (score 0):

You don't know SQL, you know MS SQL :)

Simple & correct solution depends of what you want to get. Do you wish return recordset to client? Or maybe use it in next server statements? Or something else?

MSSQL does not supports (or maybe didn't support in past) query parameters, so many years it would be the way to make parametrized queries in MSSQL - declaring variable and using them into query. Oracle supports parametrized queries, so in this case you should just do it directly:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE id = :id
```

Client uses this technique something like this:

```
with TOraQuery.Create(nil) do
try
  SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE id = :id';
  ParamByName('id').AsInteger := 45;
  Open; 
  ...
  ParamByName('id').AsInteger := 46;
  Open; 
  ...
  ParamByName('id').AsInteger := 47;
  Open; 
finally
  Free;
end;
```

Oracle didn't supports session variables instead, so MSSQL-like way isn't applicable here. Closest way to do this into Oracle is

```
declare
  p_id YourTable.ID%type := 45;
begin
  open :result for select * from YourTable where id = p_id;
end;
```

Comment: Means instead of :id, I should put value? like SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE id = 45. Is it what you are saying?

Comment: No, you should not put value, you should set this value. I'll write example.

Comment: @SanderstheSoftwarer - This is my take on this. I do not work on Oracle, but I do know that one of the main difference between Oracle and SQL Server is that to work on Oracle, you need to know `PL-SQL`. Unlike SQL, where we can just declare variables and use them, PL-SQL is a programming language and hence, you can't just use variables.  In PL-SQL the safest way to use variables is to use programming objects, like a stored proc.

Comment: (continued) - Once I heard that SQL Server is flexible in this aspect, that you can freely use variables in a new SQL window and very similarly could use them in stored proc. But if you are working with Oracle, using them in a new window is not the same as using them in a proc. I am probably not making sense because this is something I am trying to recall, but please let me know if this does make any sense. Thanks.

Comment: It's too big question for comments. Shortly, MSSQL has a single scripting language named T-SQL which supports SQL dialect and some other feautures. There is not way to access server beyond T-SQL. Oracle has SQL dialect which can be called either directly or via programming language named PL/SQL, but have no server-supported scripting capabilities.